# Непонятная проблема со сборкой Qt-проекта с помощью CMake

Tags: qt, cmake, сборка

Изначально структура проекта была такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где содержимое CMakeLists.txt следующее:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(HardwareAndSystemInformation LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
    Core 
    Gui 
    Widgets 
    WebEngineWidgets
)

set(project_headers 
    aboutwindow.h 
    datacollector.h 
    filesystemworkmodule.h 
    mainwindow.h 
    outerfileincluder.h
)

set(project_sources 
    aboutwindow.cpp 
    datacollector.cpp 
    filesystemworkmodule.cpp 
    main.cpp 
    mainwindow.cpp 
    outerfileincluder.cpp
)

qt5_wrap_cpp(project_sources_moc                     
${project_headers})

source_group("MOC Files" FILES 
${project_sources_moc})

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 
        ${project_headers} 
        ${project_sources} 
        ${project_sources_moc}
    )

    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
        Qt5::Core 
        Qt5::Gui 
        Qt5::Widgets 
        Qt5::WebEngineWidgets
    )

get_target_property(_qmake_executable Qt5::qmake         
IMPORTED_LOCATION)
get_filename_component(_qt_bin_dir         
"${_qmake_executable}" DIRECTORY)
find_program(WINDEPLOYQT_EXECUTABLE windeployqt     
HINTS "${_qt_bin_dir}")
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E
    env PATH="${_qt_bin_dir}" 
"${WINDEPLOYQT_EXECUTABLE}"
            --verbose 0
            --no-compiler-runtime
            \"$<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}>\"
)
```

Сборка завершилась вполне успешно и .exe тоже сгенерировался (запускал в Visual Studio).

С дальнейшим развитием проекта была немного изменена его структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где содержимое CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(HardwareAndSystemInformation LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
    Core 
    Gui 
    Widgets 
    WebEngineWidgets
)

set(project_headers 
    src/aboutwindow.h 
    src/datacollector.h 
    src/filesystemworkmodule.h 
    src/mainwindow.h 
    src/outerfileincluder.h 
    src/webengineview.h
    src/windowsoptions.h
)

set(project_sources 
    src/aboutwindow.cpp 
    src/datacollector.cpp 
    src/filesystemworkmodule.cpp 
    src/main.cpp 
    src/mainwindow.cpp 
    src/outerfileincluder.cpp 
    src/webengineview.cpp
    src/windowsoptions.cpp
)

set(project_resources resources.qrc)

qt5_wrap_cpp(project_sources_moc ${project_headers})
source_group("MOC Files" FILES ${project_sources_moc})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32
    ${project_headers} 
    ${project_sources} 
    ${project_resources} 
    ${project_sources_moc}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
    Qt5::Core 
    Qt5::Gui 
    Qt5::Widgets 
    Qt5::WebEngineWidgets
)

get_target_property(_qmake_executable Qt5::qmake IMPORTED_LOCATION)
get_filename_component(_qt_bin_dir "${_qmake_executable}" DIRECTORY)
find_program(WINDEPLOYQT_EXECUTABLE windeployqt HINTS "${_qt_bin_dir}")
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E
        env PATH="${_qt_bin_dir}" "${WINDEPLOYQT_EXECUTABLE}"
            --verbose 0
            --no-compiler-runtime
            \"$<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}>\"
)
```

Проблема в том, что CMake собирает его "вроде как" нормально (иногда выскакивает ошибка "Error in generation process, prject files may be invalid", но не всегда). Далее, Visual Studio не может сгенерировать .exe. И это всё, что дано - никаких подробностей насчёт ошибки CMake не предоставляет.

На первый взгляд всё кажется правильным, ведь я всего-навсего добавил несколько новых исходников с хэдерами и .qrc с изображением. Кроме того, qmake собирает проект без ошибок, и его можно даже запустить.

Я понимаю, что объяснение проблемы довольно поверхностно и не рассчитываю на гарантированный ответ, однако подозреваю, что где-то я напортачил с конфигурацией сборки и надеюсь, что опытный глаз способен хотя бы случайно найти брешь.

Comment: Очищали директорию, куда CMake генерирует файлы, после того, как изменили структуру?

Comment: Попробуйте собрать через консоль - велика вероятность, что это косяк иде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Я забыл пометить один из классов, использующего слоты и сигналы, макросом Q_OBJECT, из-за чего для него не сгенерировался MOC-файл, и, следовательно, проект некорректно собирался.